# How to add an is not null function to PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following php (PDO) statement:

```
<?php echo'<a href="' . $row['RecordURL'] .'">Call recording</a>' ?>
```

How do I add a function so that if RecordURL is null, then the following HTML is echoed instead:

```
No call recording
```

My guess so far results in syntax errors:

```
    1 <?php 
    2 if ($row['RecordURL'] !== null) {
    3  echo'<a href="' . $row['RecordURL'] .'">Call recording</a>'
    4 };
    5  ?>
```

** Edit: Syntax error output: **

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in line 3
```

Comment: `if ($row['RecordURL'] === null) { echo 'No call recording'; }` or just an `else` clause as part of your existing `if`

Comment: If you're getting syntax errors, it helps if you tell us what those errors actually are!

Comment: `if(!empty($row['RecordURL']))`  or `if(isset($row['RecordURL']))`

Comment: I'm guessing the syntax error says "you need to put the semicolon at the line where echo is".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php 
      $url=$row['RecordURL'];
      if (!empty($url)) {
         echo'<a href="' . $url .'">Call recording</a>';
      }else{
         echo 'No call recording';
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($row["RecordUrl"])){
 echo "Record url is : ".$row["RecordUrl"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable is already set from DB so just check null value using this line

```
<?php echo $row['RecordURL'] ? '<a href="' . $row['RecordURL'] .'">Call recording</a>' : 'No call recording'; ?>
```

The above should also fix your syntax error as you have `;` after `}` - It should be before `}`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 <?php 
    if ($row['RecordURL'] === null) {
       echo'No Call recording';
    }else{
       echo'<a href="' . $row['RecordURL'] .'">Call recording</a>';
    }
 ?>
```